# UITableCell Height not adjusting properly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView that lists out the details of a certain item. Some of the details require more than one line to display properly.

I am using this code to dynamically resize the cell:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 1) return 320;

    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(280, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize cellSize = [[[appDelegate.callList objectAtIndex:callID] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]
                       sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]
                       constrainedToSize:maxSize
                       lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return cellSize.height+10;
}
```

It is a cell with Right Detail style. Nothing else. The detail textlabel is size 17 font.

Using this code, I get cells that cut off the cell below:

[image: Error]

I know I could obviously just increase the +10 at the end, but then my cells would be too big for my liking.

Any help appreciated!

### EDIT

I have found the issue. The width set in maxSize was too large.

Is there any way to find out the current detaillabel with without entering it manually prior?

Comment: Is the text uppercase in `appDelegate.callList`, or are you making it uppercase in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?  Also, have you measured the width of the right detail to make sure 280 is right?  It looks like it might be a little smaller than that to me.

Comment: The text is as is. No casing has been done. I have no measured 280, that was just a random number that appeared to work haha.

Comment: Look at my answer in this link

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961951/how-to-specify-height-of-row/17963499#17963499

Comment: @AKrush95 There's no way to find the current detailLabel size (since in this method, the cell isn't created yet.)  You could make your own UITableView subclass and set it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link, its an example of Dynamic Height UITableView Cells in Xcode: It may help you.

http://samrayner.com/posts/dynamic-tableview-cells/

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 9999);
NSString *myString = @"This is a long string which wraps";
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
CGSize myStringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont 
    constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
    lineBreakMode:self.myLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

to calculate the displaying size of a givin NSString. So you can alter your cell's height according to the codes above. And also, you should reload your tableview after the heigth of some cell is changed.

Comment: Isn't that nearly identical to the code I am using? It seems as though only the detailtextlabel is having the height increased and not the whole label